# How to get unicode value of a character in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, unicode

A simple way to convert a character into Unicode. Eg. for § we need to get Unicode value "U+00A7"

Comment: To clarify: I think you want the string representation of the character's Unicode [_code point_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). (In Kotlin, all `Char` values are assumed to be [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program to convert char into Unicode. Note **char.code** is *char.toInt()* in old format

```
// Kotlin program to find Unicode value of a character
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Unicode table at https://unicode-table.com/en/
    val char = '§'
   
    // Unicode logic
    val uni= String.format("u+%04x", char.code).uppercase()

    println("The Unicode value of $char is: $uni")
}
```

Here is a Github link to try https://github.com/vidyesh95/UnicodeValueInKotlin

Comment: I suggest omitting `Locale.getDefault()` so you don't risk the possibility of some language that doesn't capitalize a-f and u the way you expect.

Comment: It would also be helpful to clarify, if the Char is surrogate, this gives the code point of the surrogate (the code unit), not the whole code point of a Unicode character.

Comment: It can be simplified to `"U+%04X".format(char.code)`